# Getting ' cannot read prop of undefined' for object when applying .replace()

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

Im trying to clean up items in an array:

```
//inside a for loop for items in an array...

var eventsLink = chunk[1];
console.log(eventsLink); 
  // this works. it returns items like these:
  https://examplesite3.com" target="_blank"><b><font>Go</font></b></a>
  https://examplesite2.com" target="_blank"><b><font>Go</font></b></a>
  https://examplesite1.com" target="_blank"><b><font>Go</font></b></a>
```

But if I try doing a basic .replace like so, it returns an error:

```
var eventsLink = chunk[1].replace(/<b>/g,"");
 > error: cannot read property replace of undefined
```

---

Actual code below. Oddly, eventsDesc does not get this error:

```
for (var i = 0, length = events.length; i < length; i++) {var chunk = events[i];
           chunk = chunk.split("<a href=\"");

           var eventsDesc = chunk[0]
                            .replace(/<\/b>/g,"")
                            .replace(/<\/span>/g,"")
                            .replace(/<b>/g,"")
                            .replace(/<i>/g,"")
                            .replace(/<\/i>/g,"");


           var eventsLink = chunk[1]
                            .replace(/<font>/g,"")
                            .replace(/<\/b/g,"");

        console.log(eventsLink);  

        };
```

Comment: Post more code, it's hard to tell from the little bit you've shown.

Comment: Have you investigated why `chunk[1]` is undefined? Perhaps your code is being run before `chunk[1]` gets a value?

Comment: are you sure every events[i] that you pass through has a valid input so that chunk[1] will be always defined as you are expecting?

Comment: ooh @matus you're right, I see some undefined items being returned

Comment: it's okay, it's Friday... :D